# "No test result files matching **/*.trx were found" in Publish Test Result Task

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am running my automation Test in Azure pipeline and using NUnit VS Test adapter and Visual studio Test task. the `.trx` file is getting attached in the
Test Run Summary. But in Publish test result task I could see the warning `No test result files matching **/*.trx were found`.

Build was successful but `.trx` file is not displayed in Publish test result task

Can you some help me what I am missing?

[image: Publish Test Results task Cofiguration]

Answer (score 6):

Because the `.trx` file is not where you specified in the Publish task, the file generated in `D:\a\_temp\....`  while you specified to search in `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)` that is `D:\a\work\1\s`.

### But the truth that you don't need at all the Publish task. the Visual studio Task do it automatically.

So you can remove this task and you still will show the test results in Azure DevOps. See the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/publish-test-results).

Comment: As you suggested, I changed search folder to "$(Agent.TempDirectory)" and Test result format as "NUnit". But still the .trx file is not displayed in published task. I could see 1 warning in Test run for Test plans task. I have attached the logs below

Comment: `##[warning]Cleanup.Run : Cleanup failed with exception : System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'd:\a\_temp\TR_86fc254b-696c-4a9f-ba45-2fc1c792daa0' because it is being used by another process.
2019-06-19T06:57:09.3485419Z    at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
2019-06-19T06:57:09.3486552Z    at System.IO.Directory.DeleteHelper(String fullPath, String userPath, Boolean recursive, Boolean throwOnTopLevelDirectoryNotFound, WIN32_FIND_DATA& data)`

Comment: It's look like process cannot access the file location Agent.TempDirectory, because it is being used by another process. Do you have any idea why i am getting that warrning?

Comment: No :/ if you remove the publish test task, can you see the tests summary?

Comment: I have removed the publish test task and re-executed. still i am getting the below warning test run** ##[warning]Cleanup.Run : Cleanup failed with exception : System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'd:\a\_temp\TR_3e32c9b3-5e71-4e56-a13a-83cdc3e1b399' because it is being used by another process.**

Comment: .trx file is attached in the test summary and i don't have any problem with that. actually i need to send the test execution report to my email id. How to achieve that?

Comment: Please open a new question regarding this

Comment: The VS task doesn't do it automatically for me

Comment: @pabrams can you share your task settings?

Answer (score 0):

Look at your screenshot:

*Test Result Format: **VSTest***.

You're not using VSTest, you're using NUnit.

Change the test result format to NUnit.